# Jaspersoft report plugin for integrating tree view into inputbox control

Tags: treeview, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to jaspersoft reports .Is it possible to have dynamic tree view in the input control dialog box

Comment: Do you talk about JasperServer or about the custom web application?

Comment: Alex ,I am talking about JasperServer

Comment: You can customize this application. Information: http://jasperforge.org/espdocs/espbrowse.php?id=86&type=folder&group_id=112&parent=86 & http://www.jaspersoft.com/download/customizing-and-rebranding-jaspersoft-user-interface

Comment: thanks for replying Alex link u posted are related to customizing the user interface but i want to add a new input control i.e treemap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JasperReports Server has static lists and dynamic lists (populated by queries). It doesn't have a tree view for input controls.

If you are asking, "Is it possible to write code to implement a tree view input control?", then the answer is, "Yes. Anything is possible with enough customization." But it won't be a trivial customization.

Answer (score 0):

Tree view is not out of the box.  But it can be done if you are willing to code again the JasperDesign.  Actually, I am writting the code to generate dynamic tree view with columns on the right.